# Синонимизировать метки [mouse] и [мышь]

Tags: предложение, статус-завершено, метки, синонимы-меток

Есть две метки:

- [mouse](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/mouse) (23 вопроса)
- [мышь](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/%d0%bc%d1%8b%d1%88%d1%8c) (63 вопроса)

Надо бы их синонимизировать (главная - [мышь](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/%d0%bc%d1%8b%d1%88%d1%8c)).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Готово!

```
updating post history, 25 rows affected (pipe delimited)
updating posts, 23 rows affected  (pipe delimited)
updating PostTags associations, 23 rows affected
updating ForYou nudges, 0 rows affected
destroying 'mouse': [mouse] removed from (0 post, 0 history, 1 tag)
total: 1 tags deleted, 0 posts modified, 0 post histories modified
0 history records had empty tags; retagged to [untagged]
0 post records had empty tags; retagged to [untagged]
updating count for target tag, new count: 86
tag remapping of [мышь] and [mouse] complete!
remapping 0 synonyms
0 favorite and ignored tags remapped!
0 tracked tag badges were remapped!
Tag Synonym mouse -> мышь was approved!
```

Comment: Ты это в командной строке делаешь?

Comment: @PetLinux SQL запросы пишет xD

Comment: @aepot а мне дефолтовая подсветка больше нравилась

Comment: @PetLinux это результат работы команды по слиянию меток. Решили, видимо, что так понятнее будет, чем сложный UI рисовать.